# Mikepenz Material Drawer custom header

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I am using a custom header in mikepenz material drawer. How can i get the onClick of the header. Can I use onDrawerItemClickListener to get the click event of the custom header ?

```
result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withSelectedItem(-1)
                .withSliderBackgroundColorRes(R.color.white)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withStickyHeader(R.layout.nav_header)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(true)
                .addDrawerItems(
                       //Drawer Items
                ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {


                })
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined a header (so not the `AccountHeader`) you can get the reference to that view by calling the following after building the `Drawer`:

```
Drawer.getHeader()
```

It's very similar for the sticky header:

```
Drawer.getStickyHeader()
```

This will return you the view of the header, and allow you to set any listener you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#add-profiles-and-an-accountheader). It is mentioned in doc that how you can handle header part and its events.

Comment: I'm not using an Account Header. I'm using custom header. So i can't use withOnAccountHeaderListener.